# icomoon fonts and wordpress nav-menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menubar

I'm trying to add icons, via icomoon fonts, to the left of my text links in wordpress through the menu bar. I'm using the css that comes with the download from icomoon. I've add the class in the menu options area in the admin area of WP. The icons (fonts) DO show up on the 'li' elements but I want them to be added to the 'a' elements instead. FYI, the class that adds the font uses the :before selector. Here's an excerpt of the css:

```
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  font-style: normal;
  speak: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: $white;
}

.icon-home:before {
  content: "\68";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `[class^="icon-"] a:before, [class*=" icon-"] a:before {`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. This is the method I use.

HTML

```
<h3 class="title-style">
    <a href="#">
    <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="[insert number from icomoon]";></span>TITLE
    </a>
</h3>
```

CSS

```
.title-style > a{
    font-family: 'font name';
}

[data-icon]::before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    content: attr(data-icon);
    speak: none;
}
```

Comment: This works great if I'm hard coding the menu with html/css. But when I replace my html with the wordpress call for a menu (wp_nav_menu) I can't figure out how to make it the target the "a" instead of the "li". I have changed the css to (a.icon-home -using my example above) and what happens is, I get an "H" which is the correct character but it's not grabbing the icomoon font. Does that explanation make sense. Thanks for helping BTW.

Comment: Ah, I see. WordPress must be storing the icons in a different path, or the path may be obfuscated through the (wp_nav_menu) call. I was able to find this page, which shows the $before string for the a tag. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: it looks like you may need to change 'before' => '', to "TRUE".

Comment: OK, finally got this sorted out. I still couldn't get the icomoon fonts to target the 'a' element (so they're still targeting the 'li' element, therefore loosing my hover state on them). But I changed the 'a' elements to 'inline-block' instead of 'block' in the css and they at least align correctly next to the text.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you further. It would be nice if the fonts are able to get the same hover state as the text. I bet it has something to do with the way wp_nav_menu works. Hopefully somebody else will come in with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I'm commenting on the wrong thread, but I'm looking for a way to add an extra field to the WordPress Menus. It's recommended to use "data-icon" rather than a CSS Pseudo :before selector for speed performance. Currently, the WordPress menu does allow inline html `<i aria-hidden="true" data-icon="****"></i>`, but it would really help if I can create a new input field for the `data-icon="***"` attribute. This way, it's just a bit cleaner to add font-glyphs to menu items. Later, I hope to be able to add a select drop down menu to this field with previews of the font-glyphs in them, but first I need to be able to make proper use of the Walker for WP Menus.